# Sort a formatted date column as Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am formatting a date column to a string with only year and month name as below

```
             WITH c1 as ( 
 SELECT  FORMAT(CompletedDate,'MMMM yyyy') as FormattedDate, 
 COUNT(CASE WHEN CoId =5 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "SSS",
 COUNT(CASE WHEN CoId =3 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "EEE"
  FROM Rtml5
  where CompletedDate>='2017-01-01' AND CompletedDate<= '2017-12-31'
 group by  FORMAT(CompletedDate,'MMMM yyyy')
 ), 
 c2 As (
   SELECT FORMAT(CompletedDate,'MMMM yyyy')  as FormattedDate,COUNT(Rawew_ID) as MMM
  FROM Rawew
  where CompletedDate>='2017-01-01' AND CompletedDate<= '2017-12-31'
 group by  FORMAT(CompletedDate,'MMMM yyyy')
 )
 SELECT coalesce(c1.FormattedDate, c2.FormattedDate) as FormattedDate, c1.SSS,c1.EEE,c2.MMM
FROM c1 FULL OUTER JOIN c2 on c1.FormattedDate = c2.FormattedDate
```

And then i used the  group by  FORMAT(CompletedDate,'MMMM yyyy')  on this formatted column 
I am getting results as below

```
    April 2017
    August 2017
    February 2016
    January 2017
    July 2016
    June 2017
    March 2017
    May 2017
    October 2017
    September 2017
```

But how can i sort this as a Date column itself . I wants the results in order  Feb. 2016 , July206 , Januaty2017,Feb 2017 ....

Comment: Try applying sort to `CompletedDate`. What the format of `CompletedDate`? Please show us your complete query

Comment: add sample data & desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Order by year and month instead, they need to be in the grouping and cte result aswell.

```
WITH c1 as ( 
    SELECT  FORMAT(CompletedDate,'MMMM yyyy') as FormattedDate,
      datepart(year,CompletedDate) YearNr,datepart(month,CompletedDate) MonthNr
      COUNT(CASE WHEN CoId =5 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "SSS",
      COUNT(CASE WHEN CoId =3 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "EEE"
    FROM Rtml5
    where CompletedDate>='2017-01-01' AND CompletedDate<= '2017-12-31'
    group by  datepart(year,CompletedDate),datepart(month,CompletedDate),
      FORMAT(CompletedDate,'MMMM yyyy')
     ), 
c2 As (
    SELECT FORMAT(CompletedDate,'MMMM yyyy')  as FormattedDate,COUNT(Rawew_ID) as MMM, 
      datepart(year,CompletedDate) YearNr,datepart(month,CompletedDate) MonthNr
    FROM Rawew
    where CompletedDate>='2017-01-01' AND CompletedDate<= '2017-12-31'
    group by  datepart(year,CompletedDate),datepart(month,CompletedDate),
      FORMAT(CompletedDate,'MMMM yyyy')
 )

SELECT coalesce(c1.FormattedDate, c2.FormattedDate) as FormattedDate, c1.SSS,c1.EEE,c2.MMM
FROM c1 
FULL OUTER JOIN c2 on c1.FormattedDate = c2.FormattedDate
order by coalesce(c1.YearNr,c2.YearNr),coalesce(c1.MonthNr,c2.MonthNr)
```

Comment: Please see my full query as i am using the format to display the date in a formatted manner,

Comment: @JibinMathew I've updated the answer using your query.